# How to convert string in draft js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a string from API request like this.

```
const test = **test**↵***nice***↵;
```

The "test" should be bold and "nice" should be bold and italic.
I am using this code in my component but it shows the *.

```
this.setState({
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
      ContentState.createFromText(nextProps.value)
    ),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Draft.js by default does not have any knowledge of markdown syntax, you'd need to use a third party tool to convert markdown to a draft-consumable format. A quick google search should find you what you need; there are several such tools out there!

Here's a few:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-draft-js
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/draftjs-md-converter
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-import-markdown